# My fadeToggle() targets an element I don't want it to

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, navigation

I am trying to make a menu that can be hidden after pressing a chevron but when I press it it also hides the chevron. I know why this is (because I target the chevron's parent so it is also affected by fadeToggles' effect) but I have been trying for a while now to come up with a solution. I've tried using .not() and adding a div that only encompasses the buttons but to no avail. I want to be able to position the elements inside '#FixedMenu' with margin-left.

http://jsfiddle.net/clarinetking/2PGZS/25/

JavaScript/JQuery

```
$('#FixedMenu').fadeToggle('slow');
$('#CloseMenu').css({'opacity' : '100'});
```

---

HTML

```
<div id='FixedMenu'>
    <button class='MenuItem'></button>
    <button class='MenuItem'></button>
    <img id='Main' src='http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/8/85/Smiley.svg/800px-Smiley.svg.png'></img>
    <button class='MenuItem'></button>
    <button class='MenuItem'></button>
    <img id='CloseMenu' src='http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/d/df/Chevron_up_font_awesome.svg'></img>
</div>
```

Comment: If your element is inside a DIV that's about to hide, how you expect that element to be visible? Pure logic.

Comment: Is this what you want? http://jsfiddle.net/pC677/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you need the image inside of `#FixedMenu` I went about this a different way.

You can't fadeToggle the parent otherwise everything inside will hide. What I am doing is adding and removing a class to change the css to have the same effect.

Here is the jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var position = 0;
    $('#CloseMenu').click(function () {
        position += 180;
        $('#FixedMenu').toggleClass('active');
        $('#Main, .MenuItem').fadeToggle();
        $('#CloseMenu').css({
            '-webkit-transform': 'rotate(' + position + 'deg)',
                '-moz-transform': 'rotate(' + position + 'deg)',
                '-o-transform': 'rotate(' + position + 'deg)',
                '-ms-transform': 'rotate(' + position + 'deg)',
                'transform': 'rotate(' + position + 'deg)'
        });
    });
});
```

The css I changed,

```
#FixedMenu.active {
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.0);
}
```

Finally, here is a fiddle: [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/Josh_Powell/2PGZS/34/)

Comment: Now THAT was clever! How does it work though because I've never seen active or what you used to change the CSS. Was it maaaaaagggiiiccc?

Comment: No the class active is based on what you name it, active is just a very common name used. This is just adding and removing a class, not hiding the element. Therefore since the element is not hidden the children can still be visible.

Answer (score 2):

Put the image outside div and it will work fine :

http://jsfiddle.net/2PGZS/26/

```
<div id='FixedMenu'>
    <button class='MenuItem'></button>
    <button class='MenuItem'></button>
    <img id='Main' src='http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/8/85/Smiley.svg/800px-Smiley.svg.png'></img>
    <button class='MenuItem'></button>
    <button class='MenuItem'></button>
</div>
<img id='CloseMenu' src='http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/d/df/Chevron_up_font_awesome.svg'></img>
```

Comment: Sorry! I should've said I am going to use a margin positioning system to align everything but when I do this it doesn't margin correctly

Answer (score 1):

See if it fits your needs:

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2PGZS/28/)

```
$('#FixedMenu').children().not(this).fadeToggle('slow');
```

Comment: Great! Can I make the grey div go away though?

Comment: @Clarinetking just make the grey color to white.Will it be ok.